# Pseudocode to find the longest run within an array

Tags: pseudocode

I know that A run is a sequence of adjacent repeated values , How would you write pseudo code for computing the length of the longest run in an array  e.g.

5 would be the longest run in this array of integers.

1 2 4 4 3 1 2 4 3 **5 5 5 5** 3 6 5 5 6 3 1

Any idea would be helpful.

Comment: I think there's a pseudocode library for that. But seriously, you have to show some effort on your part. This is really a trivial task. Is this homework? Also, if this is supposed to be pseudocode, the Java tag is unnecessary.

Answer (score 12):

```
def longest_run(array):
  result = None
  prev = None
  size = 0
  max_size = 0
  for element in array:
    if (element == prev):
      size += 1
      if size > max_size:
        result = element
        max_size = size
    else:
      size = 0
    prev = element
  return result
```

**EDIT**

Wow. Just wow! This pseudocode is actually working:

```
>>> longest_run([1,2,4,4,3,1,2,4,3,5,5,5,5,3,6,5,5,6,3,1])
5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
max_run_length = 0;
current_run_length = 0;
loop through the array storing the current index value, and the previous index's value 
  if the value is the same as the previous one, current_run_length++;
  otherwise {
    if current_run_length > max_run_length : max_run_length = current_run_length
    current_run_length = 1;
  }
```

Comment: You could also optimise the exit - when you're not in a run and the current index reaches length-max_run_length, you can quit, as there aren't enough items left to make a longer run... Possibly unnecessary depending on the size of dataset involved!

Answer (score 0):

Here a different functional approach in Python (Python looks like Pseudocode). This code works only with Python 3.3+. Otherwise you must replace "return" with "raise StopIteration".

I'm using a generator to yield a tuple with quantity of the element and the element itself. It's more universal. You can use this also for infinite sequences. If you want to get the longest repeated element from the sequence, it must be a finite sequence.

```
def group_same(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    last = next(iterator)
    counter = 1
    while True:
        try:
            element = next(iterator)
            if element is last:
                counter += 1
                continue
            else:
                yield (counter, last)
                counter = 1
                last = element
        except StopIteration:
            yield (counter, last)
            return
```

If you have a list like this:

```
li = [0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 12, 'Text', 'Text', 'Text2']
```

Then you can make a new list of it:

```
list(group_same(li))
```

Then you'll get a new list:

```
[(2, 0),
 (1, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (2, 5),
 (1, 6),
 (3, 7),
 (1, 12),
 (2, 'Text'),
 (1, 'Text2')]
```

To get longest repeated element, you can use the max function.

```
gen = group_same(li) # Generator, does nothing until iterating over it
grouped_elements = list(gen) # iterate over the generator until it's exhausted
longest = max(grouped_elements, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Or as a one liner:

```
max(list(group_same(li)), key=lambda x: x[0])
```

The function max gives us the biggest element in a list. In this case, the list has more than one element. The argument key is just used to get the first element of the tuple as max value, but you'll still get back the tuple.

```
In : max(list(group_same(li)), key=lambda x: x[0])
Out: (5, 1)
```

The element 1 occurred 5 times repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
int main()
{
    int a[20] = {1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 6, 5, 5, 6, 3, 1};
    int c=0;
    for (int i=0;i<19;i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == a[i+1])
        {
            if (i != (i+1))
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << c-1;
    return 0;
}
```